# How do I diagnose SharePoint not returning results from a list when only numbers are entered in the search query?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list that has a set of vendor name in them. Some of them have only letters in them:

- Super Duper
- Super Awesome
- Mega Awesome

Some of them have numbers at the beginning:

- 1 Super Awesome
- 789 Mega Cool
- 567IncrediblyHip

When I query the API for `Super`, it will return `Super Duper`, `Super Awesome` and `1 Super Awesome`, as expected. But when I query it for `567`, it will return nothing until I specify `567I`, at which point it will return `567IncrediblyHip`.

Here is the code I am using to build the search query:

```
public async Task<IList<VendorDto>> SearchVendors(string vendorLabel, bool includeInactive)
{
    var searchBuilder = new SearchBuilder(_sharePointClient, _query);
    var selectProperties = GetSelectedProperties();

    var vendorTypeList = new List<string>() { ContractVendorTypes.V, ContractVendorTypes.SF };

    if (includeInactive) { vendorTypeList.Add(ContractVendorTypes.IA); }

    searchBuilder
        .WithString(SharepointManagedProperties.VendorLabel, vendorLabel)
        .WithAnyString(SharepointManagedProperties.VendorType, vendorTypeList)
        .WithSort(new List<SortField>() { new(SharepointManagedProperties.VendorLabel, ListSortDirection.Ascending) })
        .WithSelect(selectProperties);


    var searchResults = await searchBuilder.SearchAsync();

    return searchResults.Items.Select(row => new VendorDto
    {
        Id = row[SharepointManagedProperties.ListItemId].ToInt(),
        Label = RemoveComputedStringPrefix(row[SharepointManagedProperties.VendorLabel]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty),
    }).OrderBy(v => v.Label).ToList();
}
```

Here are the relevant methods from the SearchBuilder:

```
public ISearchBuilder WithString(string field, string? stringValue)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
    {
        SearchOptions.RefinementFilters.Add($"{field}:string(\"{stringValue}*\")");
    }

    return this;
}

public ISearchBuilder WithAnyString(string field, IEnumerable<string>? stringValues, bool exact = false)
{
    if (stringValues != null && stringValues.Any())
    {
        var types = string.Join(", ", stringValues.Select(s => exact ? $"equals(\"{s}\")" : s));
        types = stringValues.Count() > 1 ? $"or({types})" : types;
        SearchOptions.RefinementFilters.Add($"filter({field}:{types})");
    }

    return this;
}

public ISearchBuilder WithSelect(IEnumerable<string> properties)
{
    SearchOptions.SelectProperties.AddRange(properties);
    return this;
}

public ISearchBuilder WithSort(IEnumerable<SortField>? sortFields)
{
    if (sortFields != null)
    {
        foreach (var sort in sortFields)
        {
            WithSort(sort.Field, sort.Direction);
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```